# Get First login record and last logout record for each date

Tags: ms-access

Sorry for my bad english. I have a database

```
   Id   Personel_ID          DateTime
    1      1          21.02.2018 07:31:00 
    2      1          21.02.2018 08:20:00 
    3      1          21.02.2018 18:15:00 
    4      2          21.02.2018 07:15:00 
    5      2          21.02.2018 07:18:00 
    6      2          21.02.2018 16:25:00
    7      2          21.02.2018 18:29:00 
    8      1          22.02.2018 08:32:00 
    9      1          22.02.2018 08:42:00
    10     1          22.02.2018 17:00:00 
    11     1          22.02.2018 18:01:00
    12     2          22.02.2018 08:20:00
    13     2          22.02.2018 09:10:00
    14     2          22.02.2018 17:50:00
```

What I want to do is

```
    Id   Personel_ID     Date        Login Time    Logout Time
    1      1          21.02.2018      07:31:00       18:15:00
    2      2          21.02.2018      07:15:00       18:29:00 
    3      1          22.02.2018      08:32:00       18:01:00
    4      2          22.02.2018      08:20:00       17:50:00
```

I want to get a Personel_ID's first record of a date as login time and last record of a date is logout time. I hope you understand

Comment: Please share an attempt. You haven't shown any effort or any attempt. We're a question and answer site, not a coding service.

Comment: I tried various attempts but couldn't achieve anything so I asked from scratch

Comment: You usually get more feedback when you actually share one of those attempt. However, the answer provided by Gustav should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be:

```
Select
    Personel_ID,
    DateValue([DateTime]) As [Date],
    Min(TimeValue([DateTime])) As [Login Time],
    Max(TimeValue([DateTime])) As [Logout Time]
From
    YourTable
Group By
    Personel_ID,
    DateValue([DateTime])
```